# Why would console Powershell File I/O run slower than in pssession?

Tags: powershell, file-io, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I've been having a weird performance issue with some Powershell that I encountered while writing a automation script to test my application.  The automation script was working fine - running the app until it crashed, zipping the logs, and going again - until I needed to capture verbose app logs (we're talking potentially gigabytes of logs after the tests are done!)

```
function SplitFile {
param (
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    $path = "textwriteroutput.log"
)
$file = get-item $path
$parent = Split-Path $file
$Extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
$Name = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file) 

$dir = mkdir (Join-Path -Path $parent -ChildPath $Name)

[int]$count = 0
[int]$lines = 0

$linesplit = 20000
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($file)

$outFilePath = Join-Path -Path $dir -ChildPath "${name}_$count.$extension"

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outFilePath)

try {
    while ( $line = $reader.ReadLine() ) {
        $lines++
        $writer.WriteLine("$line") 
        if ( $lines -ge $linesplit ) {
            $lines = 0
            $writer.Flush()
            $writer.Close()
            $count++
            $outFilePath = Join-Path -Path $dir -ChildPath "${name}_$count.$extension"
            $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outFilePath)
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $writer.Close()
    $reader.Close()
}

return $dir

}
```

I was running the automation script from a powershell console window in a VM accessed through an RDP session since some aspects of the automation require a "screen" to move mouse, click, and screenshot.  When the code got to this function though to split a large log file into smaller chunks, it slowed down tremendously, to the point where it was taking about a minute per KB to break the log file down.

After many iterations on trying to figure out why the code was so slow I ended up breaking the split code into its own file, and found something odd - if I ran the same SplitFile function in a remote pssession from my laptop (e.g. enter-psssession), it ran reasonably fast. If I ran SplitFile from the VM's powershell console - just the function loaded from a file in a fresh Powershell console window- it ran slow.

I know if I want performance I should write a native app, but the PoSH-in-pssession gives good enough performance.  I did end up writing an exe to split the files, but the next step in the script is Compress-Archive and that's also running slow, I presume for the same reason.  What's different about a enter-pssession Powershell prompt from a remote machine that makes file I/O go so much faster than the Powershell console in the VM-RDP desktop?  Is there a way from the script running with a screen to get the same I/O performance as from the pssession console?

Comment: Your function looks good, probably might be preferable to use `.Dispose()` instead of `.Close()` but aside from that looks good. It is odd you're getting better results running this remotely instead of running it locally. Is there something we're not seeing in your code, like the use of `Write-Progress` somewhere ?

Comment: Nothing stands out really. The console host in Windows 10 is terribly slow, so you might expect a skew in wallclock time if your functions outputs a lot of stuff, but since you're not outputting anything that can't be the culprit. Does the server have some overzealous security software installed perhaps? A DLP sensor that injects itself into desktop processes, perhaps?

Comment: Regarding compressing files also being slow, you can give [this function](https://github.com/santysq/Compress-BigFiles) a try, I promise it will be faster. There are some performance measurements in that repo